# tkinterのcouldn't connect to display ":10.0"エラーについて

Tags: python, tkinter

win10機からubuntu 18.04LTS機にvnc接続して実行したところ以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
root@kawasakih2sx-desktop:/home/takumii/ss# python test2.py
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    plt.scatter(x,y,s=20)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2858, in scatter
    __ret = gca().scatter(
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 935, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 578, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 525, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3218, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1008, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":10.0"
```

test2.pyの中身は以下の通りになります。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(60)
y = np.random.randn(60)

plt.scatter(x,y,s=20)
```

解決方法をご存知の方はご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

※追記

win10からUbuntuへvnc接続と記載しましたが、正確にはvnc接続でリモートデスクトップを利用中、になります
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu(=Linux)でのGUI表示には**Xサーバ**という仕組みを利用しているので、GUIを起動するには
「どのディスプレイにウィンドウを表示するか」を環境変数`DISPLAY`に設定しておく必要があります。

VNCを使用しているので少しややこしいですが、プログラムをUbuntu上で実行してGUIもUbuntu上に表示するなら、環境変数DISPLAYを以下の通り設定してからPythonプログラムを実行してみてください。

```
$ export DISPLAY=":0.0"
```

参考：
[環境変数:DISPLAY: UNIX/Linuxの部屋](http://x68000.q-e-d.net/~68user/unix/pickup?DISPLAY)

Comment: ありがとうございます。>プログラムをUbuntu上で実行してGUIもUbuntu上に表示するなら、環境変数DISPLAYを以下の通り設定してから...　とありますが、単純にexport...のコマンドを実行するのみでよろしかったでしょうか？